Undefined $ jQuery in Visual Studio
Anyone could help me how to include jQuery in Visual Studio, I am having error undefined $ when I included the CDN in the HTML file before the js and I installed all the jQuery extensions in VS! I don't know what to do; any help is appreciated.
JS code:
var buttonColours = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];

var gamePattern = [];

//3. At the top of the game.js file, create a new empty array with the name userClickedPattern.
var userClickedPattern = [];

//1. Use jQuery to detect when any of the buttons are clicked and trigger a handler function.
$(".btn").click(function() {

  //2. Inside the handler, create a new variable called userChosenColour to store the id of the button that got clicked.
  var userChosenColour = $(this).attr("id");

  //4. Add the contents of the variable userChosenColour created in step 2 to the end of this new userClickedPattern
  userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColour);

  //console.log(userClickedPattern);

});

It looks like VS not predicting jQuery, I want to use jQuery by VS.

DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? Please [edit] your question to include the text.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask can perhaps help you here  Perhaps set up a working example as a snippet including how you have the references in your HTML  - which is exactly what your question is about here; those references.
